# Find every possibilitie in an array of object comparing key values

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, math

I have an specific math formula which receives three parameters and I'm trying to get from an array of object all the possibilities to run this math formula.

It's regards to sports.
Imagine a match where there are 3 possibility: Team A (win) - Team B (win) - Draw.
3 bet websites are dealing with this event. But the 3 of them have different odds values for this match.

I want to run those 3 bet websites to get all posibilities I can have for this event. Never getting more than one odd from the same bet website.

Example:

- Website A: team A (win)
- Website B: team B (win)
- Website C: draw

I'm using JavaScript for that.
Thank you in advance for you time and support.

Really appreciate that.

Here is an example of data I have to get these possibilities.
Each obj is a website and into the object, the odds are on the key "outcomes".
The array of object here has 3 objects, but it can have more

```json
[
    {
        "key": "betmgm",
        "title": "BetMGM",
        "last_update": "2022-12-14T04:30:40Z",
        "markets": [
            {
                "key": "h2h",
                "outcomes": [
                    {
                        "name": "AC Milan",
                        "price": 138
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Tottenham Hotspur",
                        "price": 200
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Draw",
                        "price": 225
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "barstool",
        "title": "Barstool Sportsbook",
        "last_update": "2022-12-14T04:30:22Z",
        "markets": [
            {
                "key": "h2h",
                "outcomes": [
                    {
                        "name": "AC Milan",
                        "price": 130
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Tottenham Hotspur",
                        "price": 220
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Draw",
                        "price": 230
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "twinspires",
        "title": "TwinSpires",
        "last_update": "2022-12-14T04:17:45Z",
        "markets": [
            {
                "key": "h2h",
                "outcomes": [
                    {
                        "name": "AC Milan",
                        "price": 130
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Tottenham Hotspur",
                        "price": 220
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Draw",
                        "price": 230
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like to receive an array with the possibilities like this:

```json
[
{
  "bookMaker": "TwinSpires",
  "name": "Tottenham Hotspur",
  "price": 230,
},
{
  "bookMaker": "Barstool Sportsbook",
  "name": "AC Milan",
  "price": 130,
},
{
  "bookMaker": "BetMGM",
  "name": "Draw",
  "price": 225,
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is quite simple. First, we take all the outcomes of the first Bet website. We shuffle them randomly.

Then we simply loop through the JSON object, which is a list of bet websites, not to mention the fact that both the number of outcomes must be the same as the number of bet websites. We assign for each bet website the next item of the shuffled outcomes. We log it to the console.

Here is the algorithm:

```
var data = [
    {
        "key": "betmgm",
        "title": "BetMGM",
        "last_update": "2022-12-14T04:30:40Z",
        "markets": [
            {
                "key": "h2h",
                "outcomes": [
                    {
                        "name": "AC Milan",
                        "price": 138
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Tottenham Hotspur",
                        "price": 200
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Draw",
                        "price": 225
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "barstool",
        "title": "Barstool Sportsbook",
        "last_update": "2022-12-14T04:30:22Z",
        "markets": [
            {
                "key": "h2h",
                "outcomes": [
                    {
                        "name": "AC Milan",
                        "price": 130
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Tottenham Hotspur",
                        "price": 220
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Draw",
                        "price": 230
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "twinspires",
        "title": "TwinSpires",
        "last_update": "2022-12-14T04:17:45Z",
        "markets": [
            {
                "key": "h2h",
                "outcomes": [
                    {
                        "name": "AC Milan",
                        "price": 130
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Tottenham Hotspur",
                        "price": 220
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Draw",
                        "price": 230
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];

start(data);

function start(data) {
    var outcomes = data[0].markets[0].outcomes;

    if (data.length != outcomes.length) {
        alert("Invalid data!");

        return;
    }

    var results = createResults(data);

    printResults(results);
}

function createResults(data) {
    var outcomes = data[0].markets[0].outcomes;
    var newOutcomesNames = shuffleOutcomes(outcomes);
    
    var results = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var currentBetWebsite = data[i];
        var currentResult = {};
        var currentOutcomes = currentBetWebsite.markets[0].outcomes;

        currentResult.bookMaker = currentBetWebsite.title;
        currentResult.name = newOutcomesNames[i];

        for (var j = 0; j < newOutcomesNames.length; j++) {
            if (newOutcomesNames[i] == currentOutcomes[j].name) {
                currentResult.price = currentOutcomes[j].price;
            }
        }

        results.push(currentResult);
    }

    return results;
}

function printResults(results) {
    console.log(results);
}


function shuffleOutcomes(outcomes) {
    var parsedOutcomes = parseOutcomesNames(outcomes);
    var outcomesLength = parsedOutcomes.length;
    var newOutcomes = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < outcomesLength; i++) {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (outcomesLength - i));

        newOutcomes.push(parsedOutcomes[random]);
        parsedOutcomes.splice(random, 1);
    }

    return newOutcomes;
}

function parseOutcomesNames(outcomes) {
    var outcomesNames = outcomes.map(o => o.name);

    return outcomesNames;
}
```

Let me know, if you need any further assistance.